# Clonar + Transferir dados para outro Form

Tags: javascript

Tenho um formulário onde preencho alguns dados e quero transferir esses dados para outro formulário após preenchimento por JS. Mas ele clona tudo direito mas nao transfere os dados que eu insiro.

```js
const copialoc = document.getElementById('copyLoc');
const copiaRefForn = document.getElementById('copyRefForn');
const copiaRefInt = document.getElementsByClassName('copyRef');

/**
 * clique no botão  +
 */
function create1() {
  duplicar('copyRefForn1', 'nossaRef1', 'copyLoc1');
}
  
let i = 0;
  
function duplicar(copyRefForn1, nossaRef1, copyLoc1) {
  const original = document.getElementById('clone');
  const clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
  clone.id = "clone" + ++i;

  clone.getElementsByClassName('copyRefForn1')[0].innertext;
  clone.getElementsByClassName('nossaRef1')[0].innertext;
  clone.getElementsByClassName('copyLoc1')[0].innertext;

  lista.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<div id='hidden'>
  <div class='espaco'></div>
  <div id='lista' class='row'>
    <div id='clone' class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://www.leirispumas.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Capturar-4.jpg" alt="amostra" style="width:100%">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class='nossaRef1'>
            <h6><strong>Ref forn: </strong></h6>
            <div>
              <div class='nossaRef1'>
                <h6><strong>Ref: </strong></h6>
                <div>
                  <div class='copyLoc1'>
                    <h6><strong>Localização: </strong></h6>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input class='verMais' type="button" id="verMais" value="Ver mais">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='espaco'></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta fazer com incremento em vez de decremento na variável clone.id. Ou seja, coloca
clone.id = "clone" + i++;